# How to use Vuetify color variables with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am trying to use some conditional logic to change the background color of a button. I have found posts on here that show you can in fact use the ternary operator to change the color prop but I have not found an example for users who liike to use the color variables defined in the theme options. If it is not possible is there a way to use the root defined variable color options?

```
            <v-btn class="mx-2"
                   fab
                   dark
                   color="{toggleEdit ? primary : secondary}"
                   @@click.stop="toggleEdit = !toggleEdit">
                <v-icon v-if="toggleEdit" dark>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                <v-icon v-else dark>mdi-check</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
```

and

```
                <v-btn class="mx-2"
                   fab
                   dark
                   color="{toggleEdit ? 'var(--primary)' : 'var(--secondary)'}"
                   @@click.stop="toggleEdit = !toggleEdit">
                <v-icon v-if="toggleEdit" dark>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                <v-icon v-else dark>mdi-check</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `:color="{toggleEdit ? primary : secondary}"`, otherwise it will not be processed and passed as is.

---

And as per the docs here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props, the `color` props should be a string rather than an object, so I believe it should actually be:

```
:color="toggleEdit ? primary : secondary"
```

Hoping primary and secondary are available in local context, with color values as strings.

---

Okay if `primary` or `secondary` variables are not available in the local context (as properties in data of the wrapping component), you can access your default theme colors with:

```
:color="toggleEdit ? $vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary : 
    this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.secondary"
```

Where you can interchange `light` with `dark` as per your configuration.

If you need to set CSS variables then the property `customProperties` must be enabled in your theme configuration (check the reference links below to know how). After that you can access your color variables as given below:

```
:color="toggleEdit ? 'var(--v-primary-base)' : 'var(--v-secondary-base)'"
```

References:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#custom-properties

Comment: Using the string triggers a warning and does not seem to work: [Vue warn]: Property or method "primary" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 I have updated the answer to your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code instead:

```
<v-btn class="mx-2"
               fab
               dark
               :color="toggleEdit ? 'var(--primary)': 'var(--secondary)'"
               @@click.stop="toggleEdit = !toggleEdit">
            <v-icon v-if="toggleEdit" dark>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            <v-icon v-else dark>mdi-check</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check following snippet pls:

```css
* {
  --primary: goldenrod;
  --secondary: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-btn class="mx-2"
               fab
               dark
               :color="toggleEdit ? 'var(--primary)': 'var(--secondary)'"
               @click.stop="toggleEdit = !toggleEdit">
            <v-icon v-if="toggleEdit" dark>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            <v-icon v-else dark>mdi-check</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data() {
        return {
          toggleEdit: false
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```